# Kubuntu crashes randomly (Kali too)

Tags: linux, kali-linux, freeze, crash, kubuntu

I have installed Kubuntu and then uninstalled it because I noticed that from time to time, it freezes and I have to reboot every time. 
I thought maybe there was a problem with my distribution
so I installed Kali. 
Still have the same problem. 
I don't know how to debug this.

This is the stack error before the reboot
that I got from `journalctl --no-pager -b -p err`:

```
juil. 22 20:50:54 pc-240 kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20221020/psobject-22>
juil. 22 20:50:54 pc-240 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS06._>
juil. 22 20:50:54 pc-240 kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20221020/psobject-22>
juil. 22 20:51:03 pc-240 lightdm[1025]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
juil. 22 20:51:03 pc-240 lightdm[901]: pam_systemd(lightdm-greeter:session): Failed to release session: Transpor>
```

And this is the log from syslog just before the crash:

```
2023-07-23T01:32:35.831810+02:00 pc-240 systemd[1112]: Closed pipewire.socket - PipeWire Multimedia System Socket.
2023-07-23T01:32:35.831961+02:00 pc-240 systemd[1112]: Removed slice app.slice - User Application Slice.
2023-07-23T01:32:35.832016+02:00 pc-240 systemd[1112]: Reached target shutdown.target - Shutdown.
2023-07-23T01:32:35.832075+02:00 pc-240 systemd[1112]: Finished systemd-exit.service - Exit the Session.
2023-07-23T01:32:35.832135+02:00 pc-240 systemd[1112]: Reached target exit.target - Exit the Session.
2023-07-23T01:32:35.867762+02:00 pc-240 systemd[1]: user@125.service: Deactivated successfully.
2023-07-23T01:32:35.868273+02:00 pc-240 systemd[1]: Stopped user@125.service - User Manager for UID 125.
2023-07-23T01:32:35.900913+02:00 pc-240 systemd[1]: Stopping user-runtime-dir@125.service - User Runtime Directory /run/user/125...
2023-07-23T01:32:35.905911+02:00 pc-240 systemd[1]: run-user-125.mount: Deactivated successfully.
2023-07-23T01:32:35.906538+02:00 pc-240 systemd[1]: user-runtime-dir@125.service: Deactivated successfully.
2023-07-23T01:32:35.906689+02:00 pc-240 systemd[1]: Stopped user-runtime-dir@125.service - User Runtime Directory /run/user/125.
2023-07-23T01:32:35.907612+02:00 pc-240 systemd[1]: Removed slice user-125.slice - User Slice of UID 125.
2023-07-23T01:32:35.907695+02:00 pc-240 systemd[1]: user-125.slice: Consumed 1.698s CPU time.
2023-07-23T01:32:36.028045+02:00 pc-240 rtkit-daemon[1135]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 2 users.
2023-07-23T01:32:36.028352+02:00 pc-240 rtkit-daemon[1135]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 2 users.
2023-07-23T01:32:36.048529+02:00 pc-240 rtkit-daemon[1135]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 2 users.
2023-07-23T01:32:36.048876+02:00 pc-240 rtkit-daemon[1135]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 2 users.
2023-07-23T01:32:36.049688+02:00 pc-240 rtkit-daemon[1135]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 2 users.
2023-07-23T01:32:36.050021+02:00 pc-240 rtkit-daemon[1135]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 2 users.
2023-07-23T01:32:36.073019+02:00 pc-240 rtkit-daemon[1135]: Successfully made thread 2200 of process 1961 owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
2023-07-23T01:32:36.073102+02:00 pc-240 rtkit-daemon[1135]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 2 users.
2023-07-23T01:32:36.435551+02:00 pc-240 rtkit-daemon[1135]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 2 users.
2023-07-23T01:32:36.435834+02:00 pc-240 rtkit-daemon[1135]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 2 users.
2023-07-23T01:32:37.067011+02:00 pc-240 rtkit-daemon[1135]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 2 users.
2023-07-23T01:32:37.067334+02:00 pc-240 rtkit-daemon[1135]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 2 users.
2023-07-23T01:32:37.073361+02:00 pc-240 rtkit-daemon[1135]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 2 users.
2023-07-23T01:32:37.073794+02:00 pc-240 rtkit-daemon[1135]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 2 users.
2023-07-23T01:32:37.081884+02:00 pc-240 rtkit-daemon[1135]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 2 users.
2023-07-23T01:32:37.082252+02:00 pc-240 rtkit-daemon[1135]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 2 users.
2023-07-23T01:32:39.278087+02:00 pc-240 systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
2023-07-23T01:32:41.636986+02:00 pc-240 rtkit-daemon[1135]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 2 users.
2023-07-23T01:32:41.637263+02:00 pc-240 rtkit-daemon[1135]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 2 users.
2023-07-23T01:32:44.193245+02:00 pc-240 rtkit-daemon[1135]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
2023-07-23T01:32:44.193456+02:00 pc-240 rtkit-daemon[1135]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
2023-07-23T01:32:49.077356+02:00 pc-240 systemd[1]: systemd-fsckd.service: Deactivated successfully.
2023-07-23T01:32:50.403618+02:00 pc-240 systemd-timesyncd[887]: Contacted time server [2a01:b740:a20:4000::1f2]:123 (2.debian.pool.ntp.org).
2023-07-23T01:32:50.404114+02:00 pc-240 systemd-timesyncd[887]: Initial clock synchronization to Sun 2023-07-23 01:32:50.402305 CEST.
2023-07-23T01:32:50.880368+02:00 pc-240 systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
2023-07-23T01:32:53.130602+02:00 pc-240 rtkit-daemon[1135]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
2023-07-23T01:32:53.130929+02:00 pc-240 rtkit-daemon[1135]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
2023-07-23T01:32:53.132649+02:00 pc-240 rtkit-daemon[1135]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
2023-07-23T01:32:53.133110+02:00 pc-240 rtkit-daemon[1135]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
2023-07-23T01:32:53.159458+02:00 pc-240 rtkit-daemon[1135]: Successfully made thread 2713 of process 2295 owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
2023-07-23T01:32:53.159551+02:00 pc-240 rtkit-daemon[1135]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@2023-07-23T08:4
```

And I am using:

```
Distributor ID: Kali
Description:    Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Release:        2023.2
Codename:       kali-rolling
```

And these are my partitions:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931,51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD10SPZX-80Z
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: C45E29FA-75DD-46C8-AF15-B64B7A5A7CD3

Device     Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 1953523711 1953521664 931,5G Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/sdb: 119,24 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Disk model: KINGSTON RBUSNS8
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 908CCCBC-7544-495F-81A3-195BE53BCE0A

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1       2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sdb2    1050624 248068095 247017472 117,8G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb3  248068096 250068991   2000896   977M Linux swap
```

Note that I used to have Windows and get a blue screen error. 
I solved that by modifying some stuff in the registry. 
I went to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Intelppm
```

and set `Start` DWORD value to 4 (by default it is 3).

Comment: It seems that you are trying to use Kali (from `https://www.kali.org`: __Kali Linux__ is an open-source, Debian-based Linux distribution geared towards various information security tasks, such as Penetration Testing, Security Research, Computer Forensics and Reverse Engineering. ) as a general purpose Linux. This is unwise.

Comment: The Kali crash is far more likely than the Lubuntu crash, and hence less relevant

Comment: I have updated my post with syslog before crashing

Comment: I have two doubts: **1.** Is Kali linux the only distro or OS that gives you problem? **2.** the only error I see is about ACPI; have you tried booting with `acpi=off` kernel parameter?

Comment: Kali is not the only distro. I have tried Kubuntu and it is the same thing. (I used to have Windows and get blue screen error that i have solved with modifying some stuff in regedit).
I could try booting with acpi=off but it seems that this error is normal apparently..
I also have just updated my BIOS and my laptof just froze again.

Comment: @Lucifers similar issue on different OSes: it looks like an hardware issue; please share your Windows fixes too

Comment: @mattia.b89 I found the fix that I have been doing on Windows : I would go to Registry Editor and then go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Intelppm and set "Start" DWORD value to 4 (by default it is 3)

Answer (score 0):

*A rapid search shows an issue with Intel Power Management (intelppm.sys) on Windows;

that component is strictly related to hardware;*

as I have already commented under OP, `acpi=off` could fix the issue but as you say later, it caps CPU cores to one;
**another fix**, is to disable or limit power management from BIOS/UEFI firmware (we do not know what machine/hardware you have but decent manufacturers allow you to more or less fine tuning this setting too);

the second one can be a temporary fix (like the former one) due to affected performance and in the meantime you can look for a proper solution (if it exists) or wait for a newer kernel version that helps you;

*NB: power management is a delicate side of a kernel (both Linux and Windows) because ties both hardware, firmware and software: I suggest you to deeply search for similar issues on Linux and open a Kernel bug report if it is not already present.*

Comment: could be a more appropriate/delicate `acpi=off` **kernel parameter** who are able to turn off the puzzling hardware component; or maybe **disabling a kernel module** would be a solution;

Comment: The analogy  with the Windows problem helped me find this parameter intel_idle.max_cstate that I set to 1 in my kernel. Haven't crashed so far!

Answer (score -1):

My vote goes for `noacpi` or `acpi=no` on the `Linux` line in `grub`. Those are equivalent module directives. So, when `grub` appears, hit `e` for edit. Go to your `Kernel` line marked `Linux`. Delete `quiet`, so you can see  what's going on on bootup.

Put in your `acpi` command, and check out how things  go. If it's smooth, go to `/etc/default/grub` and make the setting permanent. Of course nothing  in `Kali` is where it's supposed to be, so you might have to hunt a bit.

I don't use Kali, b ecause it's not a desktop OS, it's a pen tester.

Comment: The command that worked for me is acpi=off


When doing this, I have noticed that I have been using only 1 CPU instead of using 8 CPU cores... probably a side effect of disabling acpi right?

Comment: I haven't crashed so far... But I can't work with only 1 CPU!